# Connection refused при отправке зарпоса из контейнера React к контейнеру Nginx

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, docker

Пытаюсь запустить приложение Django-React внутри докера, когда начинаю тестировать приложение React появляется данная ошибка

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost/media/filer_public/03/58/0358cfac-1ac5-4caa-8b6b-bd20361dd878/import_filesa0a0b76730363b11ebb8a73cf86249c70c_b167f69b364a11ebb8a73cf86249c70c.jpg failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

Обратите внимание на `_next`

[image]

Как я понимаю, внутри контейнера React идет запрос на `localhost:80`, но так как в данном контейнере такого адреса не существует, то поднимается это исключение.
Картинки, которые идут просто запросом на `localhost:80/media/filer.../` получают ответ.

На данный момент я передаю адрес api подобным образом через .env файл

```
BACKEND_ADDRESS=localhost:80
```

Есть ли возможность передать адрес контейнера Nginx в React контейнер?
Или есть какие-то другие способы решения проблемы?

docker-compose.yml

```html
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - media:/code/media/
      - static:/code/staticfiles/
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - backend

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - backend

  app:
    container_name: django_app
    build: .
    command: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --workers=4 --threads=4 --access-logfile -
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - media:/code/media/
      - static:/code/staticfiles/
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - backend

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A project worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - app
    networks:
      - backend

  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - nginx

networks:
  backend:
    driver:
      bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
  media:
  static:
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. все контейнеры в одной сети `backend` можете использовать имя сервиса `nginx`  или имя контейнера.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ!
Я пробовал передать адрес подобным оброазом `nginx | nginx:80 | http://nginx:80`, но ошибка оставлась. 
Но если я пробовал отправить запрос из контейнера react в контейнер nginx посредством `curl nginx:80`, то все прекрасно работало